# how to add content to the paper-toolbar so it appears right at the top?

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I'm trying to modify default paper toolbar behavior namely making content appear right at the top of the bar. Poking at chrome developer tool, I found that if I remove height and padding from:

```
.toolbar-tools.paper-toolbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

My top and bottom sections of the toolbar appear without any gaps from top(height), bottom(height) and left(padding) sides:

```
    <paper-toolbar>
     <div class="top">
      <p>Top text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="bottom">
      <p>Bottom text</p>
     </div>
    </paper-toolbar>
```

I tried adding css rules to `.top` , `.bottom` and `.toolbar-tools` but that doesn't seem to make any effect and original rules stand. I was wondering if there's any way of removing margins for .top and .bottom sections of the paper-toolbar via:

```
    paper-toolbar {
      --paper-toolbar-background: black; 
      --paper-toolbar-color: red;
      --paper-toolbar: {
        font-size: 15px;
        height: 200px;
      }; 
    }
```

Or am I better off just creating custom toolbar myself?

edit:
here's the link to the code
https://github.com/T0MASD/webcomponents-playground/blob/master/app/elements/ui-navbar/ui-navbar.html

Comment: Added support for --toolbar-tools mixin, I'm not certain this is the "right" way of doing this... Comments are welcome:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-toolbar/pull/33

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[paper-toolbar](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-toolbar/blob/master/paper-toolbar.html) has one inner container (#topBar) by default and two others (#middleBar & #bottomBar) when it is set as tall.

Adding a top and bottom classes **only work when** the toolbar is set as    tall.

The inside content is moved to the middle by flexbox, so to move it to the top change the align-items style to flex-start.

Example Style:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  paper-toolbar ::shadow #topBar {
      align-items: flex-start;
  }
</style>
```

There is not a mixin for the #topBar so we have to select it with the ::shadow selector. You can do the same for the #bottomBar also.

[Here's a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sLD53wc58wrFK6mjgCn8?p=preview)

Comment: Thx. Have been dabbling with this for a bit